# Linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Could someone review my linked list code? Specificially, is the design to separate `Node` and actions to create linked list appropriate?

```
template <typename T>
class Node {

  public:
    Node() : next(0) { }
    Node(T value) : val(value), next(0) { }
    T val;
    Node* next;

  private:
    Node(const Node& nd) { }
    Node& operator=(const Node& nd) { }  
};

template <typename T>
class List {

  public:
    List() {
      begin = new Node<T>();
    }

    List(T initval) { 
      begin = new Node<T>(initval);
    }
    List(const List& inp) {
      begin = new Node<T>(inp.begin->val);
      Node<T> *tempInitial = inp.begin->next;
      Node<T> *tempFinal = begin;

      while(tempInitial->next) {
        tempFinal->next = new Node<T>();
        tempFinal = tempFinal->next;
        tempFinal->val = tempInitial->val;
        tempInitial = tempInitial->next;
     } 
  }


  void addVal(const T& val) {
    if(!begin->next && begin->val == 0) {
      begin->val = val;
    }
    else {
      Node<T> *temp = begin;
      while(temp->next) { 
        temp = temp->next;
      }
    temp->next = new Node<T>(val);
    }
  }

  bool deleteVal(const T& val) {
    Node<T>* pos = isPresentN(val);
    if( pos == 0) return 0;
    if(pos == begin) { begin = pos->next; delete pos; return 1;  }

    Node<T>* temp = begin;
    while(temp->next != pos) {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    Node<T>* delnode = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp->next->next;
    delete delnode;
    return 1;
  }



  Node<T>* isPresentN(const T& val) {
    Node<T>* temp = begin;
    while(temp) { 
      if(temp->val == val)  return temp;
    temp = temp->next;
    }

  return 0;  
  }

  bool isPresent(const T& val) {
    if(isPresentN(val)) return 1;
    return 0;
  }

  ~List() {
    Node<T>* temp= begin, *t;
    while(temp) {
      t = temp;
      temp = temp->next;
      delete t;
    } 
  }

  private:
    Node<T> *begin;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By no means an expert at C++, but a few notes:

**Node Constructor**

I would get rid of the first constructor and change the second constructor a bit:

```
Node(const T& value = T()) : val(value), next(NULL) { }
```

Two things are happening here:

- I would make it just use a default-constructed instance if one isn't passed
- You should be passing a const reference as to avoid an unnecessary copy (`val(value)` is already copying it)

**`isPresentN` is badly named**

Any time a method starts with `is` I expect a `bool` return.  I would consider renaming this to `findNode` or something similar.  (And, as Benjamin Kloster said, I would make it private.)

**Remember that your class is a template**

I suspect that most people, me included, tend to develop templated classes while pretending that T is just a plain-old-int.  You have to be careful about this though.

```
if(!begin->next && begin->val == 0) {
```

If `T` were `string`, or basically anything that doesn't implement `operator==(int)`, this line would keep your class from compiling.

As Benjamin said, just use a `NULL` `begin` when the list is empty.

**`addVal` and `deleteVal`**

I would consider renaming these `add` (or `append`) and `remove` since the consumer already knows that he's adding a value.

**Edit**

I previously suggested to use `NULL`.  After the note in the comments and a bit of googling, I've decided that my suggestion to use `NULL` was in error.  For anyone interested though, the following links outline a few interesting reasons for and against NULL:

- SO: ["*Do you use NULL or 0 (zero) for pointers in C++?*"](//stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c)
- Stroustrup: ["*Should I use NULL or 0?*"](//www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null)
  [3]: SO: ["*What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0?*"](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0)
- comp.lang.c faq: ["*If NULL and 0 are equivalent as null pointer constants, which should I use?*"](http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html)

Comment: Brilliant. I had totally missed the `begin->val == 0` part. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @ersran9 Once I have a templated class finished, I typically test it with int, string and a user defined type that does lots of dynamic memory allocation and deallocation.  Then I run the program through valgrind.  That usually takes care of forgotten lines like that one or any kind of memory issues the class may have.  (Can be a bit overkill for simple classes though.)

Comment: I disagree strongly with using `NULL`. There is no difference for the compiler, so using `NULL` can be highly misleading. `int x = NULL;` compiles just fine, so `NULL` doesn’t actually offer any information about usage to the reader. This changes with C++11 and `nullptr`, but for now, sticking to `0` is fine and encouraged by most professional C++ programmers who write about this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph For some reason I've always assumed that `NULL` is standard usage, but after some heavy googling, I've been swayed.  Will edit the post in the minute.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I disagree with you about NULL. I think the visual queue for the developer reading the code provides information. I now know it is meant to initialize a pointer. I see no advantage/disadvantage in using `0` and no disadvantage to using `NULL` but there is the advantage of the visual que. Though I am looking forward to being able upgrade my compiler to use nullptr.

Comment: @Loki But the disadvantage vanishes because `int x = NULL;` compiles so you effectively cannot rely on the visual cue. In fact, you need to be on constant guard of being misled.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't see that as a disadvantage (as nothing bad is happening). And the advantage still remains. Also that is not relavant in this context. Here we are initializing next. It is either `next(0)` or `next(NULL)`. The latter lets me know that next is `probably` a pointer and that is what I expect (thus reinforcement).

Comment: Actually, there can be a difference for the compiler -- GCC, for example, will warn if NULL is converted to an int.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: http://max0x7ba.blogspot.com/2010/03/0-vs-null-in-c.html

Comment: @Loki You are aware that this breaks the standard though? Is it enabled with `-pedantic`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: No. But I had an inkling you might. I just wanted to see if the author was being silly.

Comment: @Loki I did a bit of digging and [even though there’s a bit of controversy over the reading](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35669) it’s probably legal. Regardless of legality, I agree that it’s a good behaviour to have, that probably causes no problems. And yes, it makes my above comment obsolete. *Do* use `NULL` instead of `0`. (But better yet, `#define` your own `nullptr` as `__null` if on GCC pre-C++11).

Answer (score 11):

#### Major problem:

You are breaking the rule of three (or five).

Your class contains a RAW pointer. This means you need to override Copy Constructor/Assignment operator/Destructor. You missed the assignment operator.

```
{
    List<int>  x;
    List<int>  y;

    x = y; // This is going to cause problems.
}
// At this point when it is destroyed.
// As both x and y point at the same begin object.
```

Since you have a valid copy constructor you can just use the copy-and-swap idiom to build the assignment operator:

```
List& operator=(List rhs)        // pass by value to get copy
{
    std::swap(begin, rhs.begin); // Now swap all data members.
                                 // You could write your own swap member
    return *this;
}
```

#### Sentinels

You create your list with an initial 'Sentinel' value. This is a common technique to remove the need to check for NULL pointers in your code and can make the other functions easier to write (as you don't need to check for NULL). **BUT** to use it usefully, the list needs to be circular (last element points at first) and you must always have this unused 'Sentinel' node.

When you use this technique you should never use the sentinel as a value holding node. You should always skip over it. Your loop then is always from `begin->next` (as the first node) until `begin` (when you reach `begin` again you have gone one past the last node (hence the need for a circle).

Unfortunately your code is a mix of using sentinel and using NULL terminated list. You need to pick one and stick with it. Using a sentinel makes the code much easier to write (as you don't need to check for NULL and special case the empty list).

#### Need a tail pointer

You currently only have a head pointer.
This means when you insert into the list you always chain all the way to the end before inserting. This makes an operation that could be O(1) be O(n). Most list implementations use head/tail pointer or use a doubly linked list (one chain for each direction). This makes finding the tail trivial and maintaining the extra pointer has practically no cost.

#### Other comments:

The rest of the code assumes you were trying to use a sentinel value to make the use of the list more efficient. If you want to use NULL to indicate the end of a list rather than a sentinel, the comments will change slightly (but using sentinels is the better solution so I will move ahead from there).

Not all types have a default value (or are default constructable). So you need two versions of your node class. One to use as the sentinel and one to use that holds the data payload. Let us assume that `Node` is the version that holds the payload and inherits from the base class that just contains pointer information:

When constructing Nodes:

```
// Remove the default constructor.
// When creating a payload node it should be initialized with a value.
Node() : next(0) { }

// The constructor should take a value by const reference
// This will make sure that expensive to copy objects are not over copied.
// You should also pass a pointers to link it into the list.
// At the point it is constructed you should have that information by putting
// this code in the constructor you will make creation and use easier.
Node(T value) : val(value), next(0) { }

// Since Node is a publicly available class and not designed to be copied
// You should (and have) disable the copy constructor and assignment operator.
//
// Alternatively if you make Node a private Type inside the List class then
// this is not needed.   
private:
Node(const Node& nd) { }
Node& operator=(const Node& nd) { }
```

Construct list and insert sentinel as expected.

```
List() {
  begin = new BaseNode();  // Note I changed the type BaseNode
                           // Note: BaseNode constructor will make next point
                           //       back at itself.
}
```

When you use this constructor, you should also insert a sentinel. So the list always has a sentinel value no matter how it is created. Then you can just add the value as normal.

```
List(T initval) { 
  begin = new BaseNode();
  addVal(initval);
}
```

Adding a node is a common task with its own specific method `addVal()` of doing this. Use this common method to do the actual work of adding a node. This prevents duplicating of code and makes sure that adding a node is consistently done (Note your current `addVal()` is not very efficient but I will address that separately.

```
    List(const List& inp) {
      begin = new Node<T>(inp.begin->val);
      Node<T> *tempInitial = inp.begin->next;
      Node<T> *tempFinal = begin;

      while(tempInitial->next) {
        tempFinal->next = new Node<T>();
        tempFinal = tempFinal->next;
        tempFinal->val = tempInitial->val;
        tempInitial = tempInitial->next;
     } 
  }

// Could look like this:
List(List const& rhs)
{
      begin = new BaseNode<T>();  // sentinel.

      Node<T>* begin = inp.begin;
      for(Node<T>* loop = begin->next; loop != begin; loop  = loop->next);
      {
           addVal(loop->val);
      }
}
```

In your version here you seem to overwrite the sentinel.
This is wrong as if you add 0 multiple times it will only be added once. Leave the sentinel alone and just concentrate on adding a new node each time.

```
void addVal(const T& val) {
if(!begin->next && begin->val == 0) {
  begin->val = val;
}
```

Here you assume that last node is NULL-terminated.
But in the copy constructor you assume that the list is circular.

```
else {
  Node<T> *temp = begin;
  while(temp->next) { 
    temp = temp->next;
```

I would go with the circular list (using sentinels). Also each time you add a value you must traverse the whole list to find the end. It would be easier to keep track of the last value using two pointers in List object; `begin` (points at the sentinel) and `end` (points at the last inserted node (or at the sentinel if empty list)).

Using a sentinel the insert becomes.

```
void addVal(const T& val)
{
    Node<T>* last = findlast(begin); // not needed if you have a last member.
                                
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node(val, last, begin);
                                //   ^^^^         node before the new node
                                //         ^^^^^  node after the new node.
}
```

Deleting items from a singly linked list is a pain (as you need the proceeding item). Doubly linked lists are a lot easier (in my opinion) to use because of this. But again you are potentially deleting the sentinel here.

You also search the list twice: the first time you search to find the value, then you search the list to find the node preceding the one you want to delete.

```
  bool deleteVal(const T& val) {
    Node<T>* pos = isPresentN(val);
    if( pos == 0) return 0;
    if(pos == begin) { begin = pos->next; delete pos; return 1;  }

    Node<T>* temp = begin;
    while(temp->next != pos) {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
```

You can simplify this and just look for the value by checking the value of the next node. Note: The same code works for a NULL-terminated list (just change `begin` into `NULL`).

```
Node<T>* loop = begin;
while(loop->next != begin && loop->next.val != val)
{
    loop = loop->next;
}
// Now loop->next is either begin or points at the node we are looking for.
if (loop->next != begin)
{
    Node<T> old = loop->next;
    loop->next = old->next;
    delete old;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions.I have some doubts though 1. the std::swap uses the copy constructor [ which performs the deep copies anyway- hence suited in this scenario. ] - Is my understanding correct here? 2 . When you say circular linked list - you mean => [sentinal] -> [some elements here] -> [last element] -> [the initial sentinal]. Is this right?

Comment: Also, you remarked that "But in the copy constructor you assume that the list is circular.". I didn't get that part - the loop      `while(tempInitial->next)` will go on till the last element. I wrote that code for a singly linked list. Did I make a mistake here, or am I not understanding this right?

Comment: Opps. Your copy constructor does assume NULL termination. You confused me with your naming convention `tempFinal`. mea culpa.

Comment: If your first comment is about the assignment operator then: 1: std::swap() on pointers just swaps the pointers (there is no deep copy). **But** the assignment operator **must** do a deep copy and thus is achieved by using the copy constructor which is used implicitly when we pass by value (please read up on the copy swap idiom).

Comment: The circular list: `you mean => [sentinal] -> [some elements here] -> [last element] -> [the initial sentinel]`. **Yes**.

Comment: You can either use a sentinel or not. Either way is fine. But you can't combine the two methods (which you seem to be doing). This will cause problems (like you have when adding zero and dropping values). Using a sentinel value makes the resulting code easier to read. Try it both ways; when you are complete compare the results. The first time you do it, it will take slightly more time as you need to think threw a couple of situations. But after you understand it you will find the resulting code is tighter easier to read and has fewer special cases.

Answer (score 3):

The overall structure looks ok, but two things:

1. If T is int and you repeatedly call `addVal(0)`, the list stays unchanged. Consider just setting `begin` to NULL, it's a more reliable way to tell if the list is empty.
2. `isPresentN` should either be private (or at least protected), or you should return a `const` pointer to the node. Otherwise, someone could accidentally change the node's `next` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I'm using isPresentN as a helper function within the class, isn't it better if I make it a private function? [ compared to returning a const pointer ]

Comment: Yep. It's always a good idea to only expose the absolutely necessary functions. And I can't imagine a scenario where you'd need to override it in a subclass, so private should be the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

There's an unnecessary copy of `value` here:

> ```
>    Node(T value) : val(value), next(0) { }
> ```

Other reviews suggest taking `value` as a const ref, but better is to accept by value but then *move* into the member.  That way, the only copying is done by the caller, and only for lvalues (and the code can work for move-only types).

```
#include <utility>

  Node(T value)
    : val{std::move(value)},
      next{nullptr}
  { }
```