# Managing a user account

Tags: c

Part 1 of 4 is complete.

I would like to know if what I have done could be improved. Please don't worry about output - that is a work in progress.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Accounts
{
   int  accountNumber;
   char accountName[30];
   double   accountBalance;
   double   lastPaymentAmount;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int count;
  FILE *cfPtrSource; 
  FILE *cfPtrDesitination; 
  char strYesNo[4];
  char mystring [200];
  char *field;
  size_t length;

  struct Accounts accounts;

//Check for the proper number of arguments. If incorrect, display a useful error message to the user and exit the program.

//print out the arguments and count the arguments

printf("Arg count: %d\n", argc);

for (count = 1; count < argc; count++)
{
  printf("%d Value entered: %s\n", count, argv[count]);
}


//check to see if there are min two arguments entered
if(!(count-1 == 2) )
{
  printf("\nERROR!! FAIL!! Please enter two arguments\n\n");
  exit(1);
}

//check to see if source data file exist
if ((cfPtrSource = fopen( argv[1], "rb" )) == NULL)
{
  printf("The source file:  %s could not be opened.\n", argv[1]);
  exit(1);
}else{
       printf("The source file: %s  was opened\n", argv[1]);
       fclose( cfPtrSource ); 
       printf("The source file: %s  was closed\n", argv[1]);
      }

//check to see if the destination file exist
if (( cfPtrDesitination = fopen( argv[2], "rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf( "The destination file:  %s could not be opened.\n", argv[2] );

//Create the file if the file does not exist.       
if (( cfPtrDesitination = fopen( argv[2], "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("the destination file: %s was not created\n", argv[2]);
    exit(1);
}else{
       printf("The destination file: %s was created\n", argv[2]);
       fclose(cfPtrDesitination);// Should I close the file at this point?
     }
     }else{

           //If the file exists, display the filename
           printf("The destiination file: %s  was opened\n", argv[2]);

           //warn the user it will be over written
           printf("Would you like to over write the file: %s (YES / NO)\n", argv[1]);

           //ask if they want to continue
           scanf( "%3s", strYesNo);
           printf("The user input was: %s\n",strYesNo);

           //Check the user response from step c (if applicable). 
           if((strYesNo[0] == 'Y') | (strYesNo[0] == 'y') )
          {
             printf("\nuser said Y\n\n");
          }else{
                printf("\nuser said N\n");
                printf("exit the progam\n");
                exit(1);
               }
         fclose(cfPtrDesitination);
        }

//Process the file if the user response is Yes otherwise exit the program
//file created/opened

cfPtrSource = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
printf("Source file opened: %s\n", argv[1]);

cfPtrDesitination = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
printf("Desitination file opened: %s\n", argv[2]);

//parses each line, populates an appropriately defined struct and writes the struct to a file in binary format

while (fgets(mystring, sizeof(mystring), cfPtrSource) != NULL)
{
  //check for a new line character and replace if it exist
  length = strlen(mystring);
  //printf("1nd: %s",mystring);

  if (mystring[length - 1] == '\n') 
  {
    mystring[length - 2] = '\0';
  }

  //printf("2nd: %s",mystring);
  field = strtok(mystring, ","); 
  printf("account Number:'%s'\n", field);
  accounts.accountNumber = atoi(field);

  field = strtok(NULL, ",");
  printf("account Name: '%s'\n", field);
  strcpy(accounts.accountName, field);

  field = strtok(NULL, ",");
  printf("account balance: '%s'\n", field);
  accounts.accountBalance = atof(field);

  field = strtok(NULL, ",");
  printf("account lastpay: '%s'\n", field);
  accounts.lastPaymentAmount = atof(field);

  printf( "struct-lastPaymentAmount: %s\n", accounts.lastPaymentAmount );
  fwrite( &accounts, sizeof(struct Accounts), 1, cfPtrDesitination );
 }

//clean up and close the files
fclose(cfPtrSource); 
fclose(cfPtrDesitination);

printf("\n\nfile closed\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, you need to split your "monster-main" into several smaller functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing super huge, but here's a brain dump:

- typedef the accounts struct so you don't have to include `struct` each time
- you have a lot of debugging type code that shouldn't be in a final program (for example, dumping back out the passed arguments)

  - typically when you're doing debugging type output, you'll want to use stderr
  - Edit: whoops, just remembered that you said to ignore output
- Lots of things wrong with this: `if(!(count-1 == 2) )`

  - You have an extra space there before the last closing parenthesis
  - Rather than abusing the left overs of the debugging loop, just check argc directly
  - use `if(argc != 2)` rather than `if(!(argc == 2))`
- I would use `return` instead of `exit` in your situations

  - The differences are going to be very subtle, but I feel like the actual intention is `return` moreso than `exit()`
  - Other than the requirement of `stdlib.h` to pull in `exit`, I'm not sure if there is actually any meaningful difference in C.
  - In C++, there is indeed a subtle but potentially important difference: `return` will have local objects destruct; `exit` will not.
- Your indentation is all kinds of crazy.

  - Short rule: Inside blocks should be indented at one level
- Your use of `if(`, `if (` and `while (` irks me. Pick either a space or no space and stick with it.
- "destination", not "desitination"
- The flow of your "ask the user if he wants to overwrite the file if it already exists" section is a bit confusing
- With regards to: `if((strYesNo[0] == 'Y') | (strYesNo[0] == 'y') )`

  - When you mean logical or (`||`), use logical or.
  - `|` does not short circuit, meaning you can run into all kinds of fun issues with this if it becomes a habit
- Some of your comments are completely unnecessary, or in the wrong place.

  - Example of unnecessary: `//clean up and close the files`
  - Example of wrong place: `//Check for the proper number of arguments. If incorrect, display a useful error message to the user and exit the program.`
  - *Also unneccessary*
- You have way too much going on in your main. Try to identify abstract concerns, push those into their own functions, and then let main chain those together:

  - Open the source file
  - Open the destination file
  - Parse the CSV
  - Write the parsed data out to a file
- You seem to have some extra headers. I'd need to look closer, but I think you just need: stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h

  - As long as the effort is fairly minimal (as it is in this application), I like to stay cross platform. `conio.h` instantly murders that.
  - Comes down to opinion though. If you're 100% sure that your application will always stay on your platform, then go at it.
- Since it's part of your assignment, it's not really your issue, but writing a struct to a file is implementation dependent.
- Your error checking could be more paranoid, but it's not strictly necessary

  - What happens if between the time you check for the existence of the file and the second time you try to open it, it's been deleted?
  - Also, you might as well keep the files open when you can rather than reopening them
- If the last character of a string pulled through fgets isn't a new line, your buffer isn't big enough. Whether or not you want to handle that though... Well, it does make things a bit of a pain.
- When possible, avoid using actual type names in `sizeof`

  - For example, if you had something like `int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * numInts);` I'd write it as `int* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));`
  - It accomplishes the exact same thing, but if you change the type of `arr` later, your allocation won't break
  - (Note: `sizeof` never actually evaluates its argument so you don't have to worry about that -- `arr` isn't actually dereferenced. Expressions just have their types deduced; they're not actually evaulated.)
  - The reason I said this: `fwrite( &accounts, sizeof(struct Accounts), 1, cfPtrDesitination );`
  - That could be: `fwrite( &accounts, sizeof(accounts), 1, cfPtrDesitination );`
  - Not particularly useful here since the type is highly unlikely to change, but... good habit to have anyway :)
- Your `fwrite` call should probably have some error checking if you want to go the paranoid route
- 100% opinion: I don't like your Hungarian-notation-esque variable names.

  - `cfPtrSource` It's a pointer to a C file: my IDE also could've told me that.
- 100% opinion: I tend to use avoid `NULL` and just check pointers as true or false `if (ptr)` instead of `if (ptr != NULL)`

  - Note: this one is highly opinion. I'm likely in the minority on this one. As Lundin noted in the comments, you get certain type safety with a NULL check that you cannot get with an implicit check. That is probably worth the 7 extra characters. A large part of this opinion comes down to me being lazy with arguably bad habits :).
- 100% opinion: If you're going the Visual Studio route, I'd go with C++, not C.

*(Note: the ones that are just blatant opinion [or more particularly, opinion I'm too lazy to argue], have been marked, but really a lot of it is borderline opinion, so take it as you will.)*

Comment: Nice review.  Why do you say that the buffer in the `fgets` call is not big enough?  Unless the entry in the file is more than 200 chars (which is possible and is not checked), it seems ok. Also, removing the \n seems unnecessary - but checking it is there would allow him to protect against > 200 chars in the line.

Comment: I have made the changes. No reason to justify or discuss the whys or why nots - everything was valid and I don't know enough otherwise.  
Somethings were done because the assignment requirements, or the instructor does it that way or thats how I got it to work


But thanks for all the tips, it definitely improves the overall code

Comment: @WilliamMorris I said that if the last character isn't a new line, then the buffer isn't big enough. Basically I was saying what you're saying. 200 characters might not be big enough. A simple way to check for that is `if (last char != '\n' && !feof(f)) { /* buffer not big enough to hold entire line */ }`. (Then again, it's been a long time since I've written anything in C, so I may be remembering this incorrectly :p)

Comment: I agree with most of the points, but I must disagree with the first point. _typedef_ hides the information about the _real_ type of information. This is a really simple program, but if you have an huge program and you want it immediately understandable you should avoid _typedef_. I think that is much readable if you are explicit

Comment: @Federico That information is obvious as can be with a reasonable naming convention though (which I should have mentioned [`Account` for example]). You're right though, it's not very "C" to omit the struct. I'm one of those new-fangled C bastardizers though :).

Comment: @Corbin I suspected that you are bastardized :P Anyway. The naming convention can be **struct_account** or **AccOUnt**. 
**struct account** is more readable and it self explains. In an open-source context, we cannot use a different convention for each program; the other programmers do not want (like) to learn your personal convention: lowCamelCase, CamelCase, something_t, UPPERCASE, mIDDLECASe, w1thnumb3r. It cause confusion.

Comment: I agree with Corbin regarding the typedef, and I'm about as much old-school C programmer as they come. Whether to typedef structs or not is _coding style_. To use typedefs is more common than not. However, the (horrible, so-called) [Linux kernel coding style guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) preaches to not use typedef, but provides a very weak rationale why. So this is a situation where there are two coding style camps and no consensus.

Comment: Likewise, using `sizeof(*arr)` instead of the actual type is also coding style and 100% opinion.

Comment: Regarding the opinion to not check against NULL explicitly, there is _almost_ a consensus to always check for NULL as in the original code. For example, `if (ptr)` would be banned by MISRA-C, while `if (ptr==NULL)` would be recommended practice. The rationale is not only because the explicit check is easier to read, but also because you add type safety, in case you meant `if (*ptr)` but accidentally forgot the *.

Comment: @Federico Every code base involves learning a coding convention. Until The One Two Style Guide comes along, that's how it will be. Better yet, as there is very little hard evidence to support the superiority of any (reasonable) coding style, basically they all come down to personal convention.

Comment: @Lundin There's no downside to sizeof(*arr) but there is a tangible (though small) benefit (and a relatively large benefit with statically sized arrays). And there's seems to be a consensus on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373252/c-sizeof-with-a-type-or-variable. (Though of course a ~4 year old SO question barely matters.) I suspect we're just going to differ on this.

Comment: @Lundin I've gotten into the "compare to null or don't compare to null?" more times than you'd think on CodeReview. The short thing: neither of us is going to convince the other. Actually, the ability to get a warning in the case you pointed out probably makes it worth the explicit `NULL` check.... But eh... Laziness :). (Nevertheless, I shall edit my answer to make it more clear that the `NULL` thing is *highly* opinionated on my part, and a rather rare opinion.)

Comment: Though C++, a rather interestingly little mini debate is in the comments here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/13062/7308

Comment: @Corbin The closest thing to an universal C coding standard we have is MISRA-C. It is starting to gain acceptance even outside the branch of embedded systems, where it is already industry de facto. What's interesting is that MISRA is no coding _style_ guide, it only bans dangerous practice. Apparently MISRA considers `if(ptr)` _dangerous_ and not just bad style. Whether this is just their opinion or if they are backed up by actual, scientific research, I don't know. ->

Comment: @Corbin Part of MISRA is based on Les Hatton's scientific population studies of bugs in real world applications, which are described in his book [Safer C](http://www.amazon.com/McGraw-Hill-International-Series-Software-Engineering/dp/0077076400) (which is quite a tough book to get through, it is more of a scientific publication than anything else). I suspect most of MISRA-C is not based on actual science though.

Comment: @Lundin Everything is just code style. The code style aims is to improve readability and avoid errors. I think that a code style is not just "use 4 space tab" or banality like this.

About *typedef*, I completely agree with the kernel coding style. If I read a portion of code of a big program for the first time, I do no want to waste my time to understand what is behind a typedef. If an apple is named 'apple' why call it 'something_round_and_red'. Avoiding typedef help the reader to understand and avoid you (programmer) to confuse about the real meaning of your custom type.

Comment: @Corbin unfortunately you are right: "they all come down to personal convention". It is not a problem if you write code for yourself or for your company. But if your code is distributed, or you submit patch to an open-source project, you cannot apply your personal convention. If you work in the aerospace sector you must write *MISRA-C* code; if you submit Linux patches you must follow its rule. There are many standards, and I think that you must take the best from each of them to write beautiful code. It does not matter if you use 4/8 space tab,but in each code style there are important points

Comment: @Corbin my very _very_ **very** personal opinion: it is right to avoid typedef like suggested in the Linux kernel code style. You save 6 char (struct), but someone else loses his time to understand it. _MISRA-C_ target is different and I understand that it can be important to define custom types

Comment: @Federico Actually the main argument for typedef:ing structs is consistency. You don't write `auto signed long int` even though it is strictly speaking more correct than just `long`, now do you? Typedef:ing structs also make them behave consistently with C++, where the extra struct keyword is made reduntant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8079/discussion-between-federico-and-lundin)