# Remove duplicates from unsorted linked list

Tags: c++, object-oriented, linked-list, pointers

Remove duplicate elements from linked list.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList{
private:
    int data;
    LinkedList *next;
public:
    void insert(LinkedList **start, int data){
        LinkedList *p = new LinkedList;
        if (*start == NULL){
            p->data = data;
            p->next = NULL;
            *start = p;
        }
        else{
            LinkedList *temp = *start;
            while (temp->next != NULL){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = p;
            p->data = data;
            p->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    void removeDuplicates(LinkedList **start){//This function removes the duplicates using the standard runner method taking 2 pointers
        LinkedList *temp = *start;
        LinkedList *temp1 = (*start);
        while (temp != NULL){
                while (temp1->next!=NULL){
                    if (temp->data == temp1->next->data){
                        LinkedList *p;
                        p = temp1->next;
                        temp1->next = temp1->next->next;
                        delete(p);
                    }
                    else{
                        temp1 = temp1->next;
                    }

                }

            temp = temp->next;
            temp1 = temp;
        }
    }

    void traverse(LinkedList **start){
        LinkedList *temp = *start;
        while (temp != NULL){
            cout << temp->data;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    LinkedList *start = NULL;
    LinkedList p1;
    p1.insert(&start, 9);
    p1.insert(&start, 8);
    p1.insert(&start, 7);
    p1.insert(&start, 9);
    p1.insert(&start, 8);
    p1.traverse(&start);
    p1.removeDuplicates(&start);
    cout << "\n";
    p1.traverse(&start);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This takes \$O(N^2)\$ time. Can we do the same in \$O(N)\$ without the use of hash table? Or if mandatory how can we implement it in C++?

How is the overall code quality of the above code? Is there any scope of improvement?

Answer (score 6):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `getchar` but doesn't `#include <cstdio>`.  Also, carefully consider which `#include`s are part of the interface (and belong in the `.h` file) and which are part of the implementation.

### Avoid raw pointers

In modern C++, we tend not to use raw pointers very often.  In this case, It would probably be better to have two different classes, one would be a `LinkedList` class and the other would be a `Node` class.  That way, instead of starting with a pointer, you can start with an object.

### Use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`

Modern C++ uses `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/1283623#1283623) for why and how it's useful.

### Match `new` with `delete`

If you allocate memory using `new`, you must also free it using `delete` or your program will leak memory.  Since you use `new` in `insert()`, you should use `delete` in the `LinkedList` destructor which you have not yet written.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` within your program is generally [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use more descriptive names

The code's `traverse` function actually prints the nodes.  For that reason it should probably be named something like `print()`.  Even better would be to have such a function take a `std::ostream&` argument so it would be possible to print to something other than `std::cout`.

### Omit `return 0`

If your program completes successfully, the `return 0` at the end of `main()` will be generated automatically, so it's not needed in C++ programs.

Comment: Thank you very much on your comments. I couldn't exactly get the destructor part. Do I need to delete all the pointers which I created using new? If yes can you help me with doing that?

Comment: Yes, you need to delete all the pointers created with `new` in your destructor.  However, in your current implementation there is an odd mix of pointers and objects.  Look at [this C++ linked list](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/linked-list-in-c) and especially the comments on it to see how it might be done.

Comment: @DhavalDoshi You might want to read about the Stack and the Heap (just search for it). The keyword *new* reserves memory on the Heap. Until *delete* is called, this part stays reserved, since the program does not know if the data is to be needed in the future or not. This is called a *memory leak*, another term you might want to search for. Lastly, if you keep on working with raw pointers, consider to learn how to use the tool *valgrind*, which is quite adept at detecting memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

In both pathes of if .. else you have the identical Code. Take it out of the condition, DRY:

```
void insert(LinkedList **start, int data)
{
    LinkedList *p = new LinkedList;
    p->data = data;
    p->next = NULL;

    if (*start == NULL) 
    {
        *start = p;
    }
    else
    {
        LinkedList *temp = *start;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to identify duplicate values in an unsorted container allowing duplicates in \$O(N)\$ time without hashing.
Nits:

- state upfront your goal coding what you present
- you tagged the question oop: move non-List members to a class `LinkedNode`
- in `insert()`, both branches of the `if`-statement share code
- Use references (there should be a trivial way "in CR" to refer to
  Scott Meyers "Effective C++"/"Effective Modern C++" or equiv.)
- don't use different notations for the same "thing"
  (initialisers for `temp` and `temp1`)
- with loops having a "while"-*condition*, an *advance to next iteration*, and possibly an *initialise*, use `for`

shot:

```
void removeDuplicates(LinkedNode *node) {
    for ( ; nullptr != node ; node = node->next) {
        LinkedNode *prev = node, *other;
        while (nullptr != (other = prev->next))
            if (node->data == other->data) {
                prev->next = other->next;
                delete(other);
            } else
                prev = other;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Sort the list using merge sort - O(nlog n).
Step 2: Remove duplicate elements iterating from second position by comparing current node against the previous one - O(n).

Overall complexity will be O(nlog n) + O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to mention the naming in your code. First, the word `data` is meaningless. Every byte in the computer is some sort of data. I realize this is a contrived example since the data doesn't actually represent anything. But in real code, you should avoid generic terms like "data," "value," "info," etc.

Secondly, naming variables `temp` and `temp1` is even less meaningful. `temp` implies a temporary variable. If these were temporary variables you'd want to know what they were temporaries of. For example, `tempPhoneNumber` or `tempAddress`. But in this case, they aren't temporaries. They are the thing you are operating on. They represent the node you are trying to match, and the node which you are testing for a match. So you should name them something like `nodeToMatch` and `nodeToTest` or `matchNode` and `testNode`, or something like that. It's much clearer. In `traverse()` we see the same problem. You could at least call it `nextNode` or something like at least slightly more meaningful than `temp`.